# google cloud, big queries cost big memory

Tags: python, google-bigquery

TLDR; querying 12.9MB in BQ costs about 540MB ram in Python. And this grows about linearly.

I'm querying some bigQuery tables. Running the following query at https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/

```
SELECT * FROM dataset1.table1, dataset1.table2
```

Results in:

```
Query complete (5.2s elapsed, 12.9 MB processed)
```

It's about 150k rows of data. When I do the same query in python the same query uses up to 540Mb of ram. If I query 300k rows this results in double the ram usage. When I do the same query multiple times the ram usage doesn't change. So my best guess is that it's using some buffer that never gets freed. I've tested whether `gc.collect()` helped but it didn't. I've also dumped my data to json and that file is about 25MB. So my question is: Why is the memory usage so large, and is there any way to change it?

My code:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.tools import run
import httplib2
import sys

projectId = '....'
bqCredentialsFile = 'bigquery_credentials.dat'
clientId = '....'  # production
secret = '.......apps.googleusercontent.com '  # production

storage = Storage(bqCredentialsFile)
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id=clientId, client_secret=secret, scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery')
    credentials = run(flow, storage)

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
svc = build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)


def getQueryResults(jobId, pageToken):
    req = svc.jobs()
    return req.getQueryResults(projectId=projectId, jobId=jobId, pageToken=pageToken).execute()


def query(queryString, priority='BATCH'):
    req = svc.jobs()
    body = {'query': queryString, 'maxResults': 100000, 'configuration': {'priority': priority}}
    res = req.query(projectId=projectId, body=body).execute()
    if 'rows' in res:
        for row in res['rows']:
            yield row
        for _ in range(int(res['totalRows']) / 100000):
            pageToken = res['pageToken']
            res = getQueryResults(res['jobReference']['jobId'], pageToken=pageToken)
            for row in res['rows']:
                yield row


def querySome(tableKeys):
    queryString = '''SELECT * FROM {0} '''.format(','.join(tableKeys))
    if len(tableKeys) > 0:
        return query(queryString, priority='BATCH')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import simplejson as json
    tableNames = [['dataset1.table1', 'dataset1.table2']
    output = list(querySome(tableNames)) 
    fl = open('output.json', 'w')
    fl.write(json.dumps(output))
    fl.close()
    print input('done')
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that the issue is in the `output = list(querySome(tableNames))` line. I'm not a python expert, but from what I can tell, this will convert your generator into a concrete list, and require the entire results to be in memory. If you iterate this line by line and write a single line at a time, you may find you have better memory usage behavior.

As in:

```
output = querySome(tableNames)
fl = open('output.json', 'w')
for line in output:
  fl.write(json.dumps(output))
  fl.write('\n')
fl.close()
print input('done')
```

Also....
when you get query results you *may* get back less than 100000 rows, since BigQuery limits the size of responses. Instead, you should iterate until no pageToken is returned in the response.

Comment: No. If i ignore the results, memory usage is the same